# Wie wird “Cochem” ausgesprochen?

Tags: pronunciation, place-name

Wie wird der Name der Stadt “Cochem” ausgesprochen?

- Mit [o] oder [ɔ]?
- Mit [x] oder [ç]
- Mit unbetontem [əm] oder betontem [e:m]?

Comment: 1b,2a,3a  würde ich sagen. Koch, wie ich Koch, + emm

Comment: @Chieron das wäre doch eine Antwort wert.

Comment: @Raketenolli angesichts der Tatsache, dass es sich ums Rheinland handelt, überlasse ich das besser den Anwohnern. Gerade Ortsnamen können manchmal überraschend sein.

Comment: Ist wie @Chieron vermutet: "Kochem" Grüße aus dem Saarland.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Cochem) sagt:

> [ˈkɔχm̩]

also ganz ohne e.

Comment: *schwa-Konsonant* und *vokalischer Konsonant* sind im Deutschen in der Regel Allophone, d.h. ziwschen deiner Variante und einem Schwa-e wäre kein nennenswerter Unterschied.

Answer (score 1):

Auf [Forvo](http://de.forvo.com/word/cochem/) kannst du die Aussprachen von Wörtern hören. Viele Wörter wurden von Muttersprachlern ausgesprochen.

Comment: Also: `['kɔxɛm]`.

Comment: Hört man sich auf http://de.forvo.com/word/cochem/ die Ausprache von Radioman an, hört man am Ende des Wortes ganz deutlich anstelle des erwarteten [m] ein [n]. Er sagt ['kɔxɛn]. Ich glaube nicht, dass das die richtige Aussprache ist.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Wer weiß? Immerhin wird *Itzehoe* entgegen Erwarten ([...hø:] oder [...ho:ə]) lieber [...ho:] ausgesprochen. Eine Meinung dazu wäre ganz interessant! Hat sich der Mann versprochen, ist das seine Eigenheit, oder ist es richtig?

Comment: unten auf der Karte kann man sehen, wo der Ausspracher ist. Ich bin kein Muttersprachler aber ich denke, bei der Aussprache gibt es auch die regionalen Unterschiede.